# How to pass a command as a command line argument by Batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

I want to pass a command as a command line argument from one batch file to another.

e.g. :

first.bat:

```
call test.bat "echo hello world" "echo welcome "
```

test.bat:

```
set initialcommand=%1

set maincommand=%2

%maincommand%

%initialcommand%
```

Comment: Hema, you need to accept answers to some of the 6 questions you've asked before. Then you'll get a better response

Comment: OMG! Someone who's been here so long that they have 6 rep and 7 questions, and they haven't accepted any answers. Quick, bring out the noose :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo. All in good fun offcourse but who can honestly say they would be using SO if there was no reputation whatsoever involved.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what you need:

`first.cmd:`

```
@echo off
set maincommand=echo hello world!
call test.cmd %maincommand%
```

`test.cmd:`

```
@echo off
%*
```

In this case `first.cmd` passes the actual command (your example just passed the constant string `"maincommand"` rather than its value).

In addition, `test.cmd` executes a command made up of *every* parameter, not just the first.

When you create those two files and execute `first.cmd`, you get:

```
hello world!
```

as expected.