# Unable to pass command line arguments to a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, cmd

> I've a batch file that is opening a FTP connection to a server and putting a file on a specified location.

Here is how my **`ftpConnection.bat`** file look like..

```
open HOST
FTP_USER_NAME
FTP_USER_PASSWD
cd TO_DIR
lcd TO_FILE_LOCATION
put THE_FILE
quit
```

and from command prompt if i run it like this **`ftp -i -s:ftpConnection.bat`** it works fine.

***My requirement is to pass HOST, USER_NAME and PASSWORD as argument***

*so i tried to use **`%1 %2 and %3`** but this is not working for me.*

**Passing the argument like this**

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop>ftp -i -s:ftpConnection.bat "HOST" "USER_NAME" "PASSWORD"
```

**also tried without the quotes but result is same, it'S showing**

> Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service
>   (sometimes called a daemon). Ftp can be used interactively.
>
> FTP [-v] [-d] [-i] [-n] [-g] [-s:filename] [-a] [-A] [-x:sendbuffer] [-r:recvbuf
>   fer] [-b:asyncbuffers] [-w:windowsize] [host]

**Followed and tried few document like** [How to pass multiple parameters in CMD to batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117795/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-cmd-to-batch-file) **and** [Batch file command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879846/batch-file-command-line-arguments)

> they suggested to use **set** and i tried it like below but result is same.

```
set host=%1
set uname=%2
set passwd=%3
open %1
%2
%3
```

Can anyone suggest me what i am doing wrong or any pointer to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you are using a text file with input and commands expected and interpreted by `ftp` command. This is not a windows batch file and can not use its syntax.

To use the required data as arguments in the call, you need a batch file that will generate the ftp script from the passed arguments

```
@echo off
  setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

  if "%~3"=="" goto :eof

  set "TO_DIR=......"
  set "TO_FILE_LOCATION=......"
  set "THE_FILE=........"

  > ftpScript (
      echo open %~1
      echo %~2
      echo %~3
      echo cd %TO_DIR%
      echo lcd %TO_FILE_LOCATION%
      echo put %THE_FILE%
      echo quit
  )

  ftp -i -s:ftpScript
```

Now, you have a batch file (let's call it `doFTP.cmd`), that you can call as

```
doFTP.cmd ftpserver userName pa$$word
```

The arguments in the command line are stored in the `%1`, `%2` and `%3` variables (`%~1` is first argument without surrounding quotes if present) and used inside the batch file to generate (the block of `echo` commands are redirected to the `ftpScript` file) the text file that ftp will handle.

Answer (score 0):

based on your use it is like

```
set host=%1
set uname=%2
set passwd=%3
open %host%
%username%
%passwd%
```

you can use the set variable back by enclosing between two %var-name% as i shown above
please give it a try

Comment: Tried as suggested above but no difference.